# Size of splitter for wxSplitterWindow

Tags: wxwidgets

I am trying to change the size of the splitter (sash) within component wxSplitterWindow, since it is too small and difficult to click on.

I found that there is a method SetSashSize in wxSplitterWindow, but it is deprecated and with comment: "this doesn't do anything and shouldn't be used at all any more". I was not able to find a new method to use for this purpose. Anyone had the same problem, any ideas?

Using wxWidgets 3.0.2. MacOS 10.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no way to customize the splitter sash thickness, but normally it shouldn't be needed because it is supposed to use the correct value for the current platform, e.g. under OS X it uses `kThemeMetricPaneSplitterHeight` if `wxSP_3DSASH` style is used. So maybe it's just the question of using the right style? `3D` is a misnomer, it basically means just "wider sash".